# Composite primary key table not populating in related entity

Tags: java, spring, jpa, composite-primary-key

My database contains a table with a composite-primary-key such that one of the keys is a foreign key, and the other is supposed to be used to get an entity from an external service. The code looks somewhat like this:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Embeddable
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class PrimaryKey implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "A_ID")
    private Long aId;

    @Column(name = "F_ID")
    private Long fId;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "JOIN_ENTITY")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class JoinEntity {
    @EmbeddedId
    private PrimaryKey pk;

    @MapsId("aId")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")
    private EntityA a;

    public getFId() { return pk.getFId(); }
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITY_A")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EntityA implements Serializable {
    ....

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   List<JoinEntity> list = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

When I get a JoinEntity saved and try to get EntityA from the database the list is not being populated, but if I get some JoinEntity from the database the related EntityA is recovered correctly. What do I do to get the JoinEntity list to be recovered with the EntityA?

Comment: Define what you mean 'the list is not being populated', is it empty or just lazily fetched? When you save your entities, are you adding your new JoinEntity to the EntityA list? You must maintain both sides of a relationship, and JPA has caching that would cause you to get back your unpopulated EntityA instance with an empty list. You can verify if this is the problem by forcing it to be refreshed using em.refresh(entityA), and then checking the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem adding an ENTITY_F table with the id and switching to a simple ManyToMany relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use FetchType.EAGER on the @OneToMany association in the EntityA class:

```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   List<JoinEntity> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

This way when you retrieve a **EntityA** from the database, its **JoinEntity**s will be automatically retrieved.

Comment: didnt work, if you look at the JoinEntity although the fetch being LAZY the EntityA is being automatically retrieved. But thank you anyway.